# Show/Hide views using Visual State Manager silverlight & PRISM

Tags: silverlight, prism, visualstatemanager

I have an application that display different datasets (users, nationality, etc) on the screen using radOutlookbar.
I have manage to load the required views in each item to display the data with no problem.

I then built views for each dataset (users, nationality, etc) to display the details about each selected item (i.e:user) within the displayed datasets.

Case:
First, I need to display the respective view for each dataset when I click on it's item.
Second, The displayed view will have an option to edit/add the displayed details.

I want to achieve this scenario using state-base-navigation.

So,
I have a PRISM region inside ItemsControl with ItemsPanelTemplate of grid to host the loaded views, basically I load the views for each dataset.

Question, 
How should I show/hide the respective view according to the selected dataset using VSM?

Question 2:
Should I be able to define another nested state inside the loaded view to enable the scenario of edit/add details for each view?

If someone have any idea to do this, will be of great help to have a starting code.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

May be there's other schemes to access VSM but I prefer to create AttachedProperty for it. Let me explain.

Here is VisualState manager

```
/// <summary>
/// Class will allow to change VisualSate on ViewModel via attached properties
/// </summary>
public static class VisualStateManagerEx
{
    private static PropertyChangedCallback callback = new PropertyChangedCallback(VisualStateChanged);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the state of the visual.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The obj.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetVisualState(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(VisualStateProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the state of the visual.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The obj.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetVisualState(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(VisualStateProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DP for 'VisualState'
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisualStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "VisualState",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(VisualStateManagerEx),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, VisualStateManagerEx.callback)
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Visuals the state changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">The d.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
    public static void VisualStateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Control changeStateControl = d as Control;
        FrameworkElement changeStateControl = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (changeStateControl == null)
            throw (new Exception("VisualState works only on Controls type"));

        if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
        {
            // Wrong thread
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[VisualStateManagerEx] 'VisualStateChanged' event received on wrong thread -> re-route via Dispatcher");
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                //() => { VisualStateChanged(d, e); }
                VisualStateManagerEx.callback
                , new object[] { d, e });    //recursive
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewValue.ToString()) == false)
            {
                //VisualStateManager.GoToState(changeStateControl, e.NewValue.ToString(), true);
                VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(changeStateControl, e.NewValue.ToString(), true);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[VisualStateManagerEx] Visual state changed to " + e.NewValue.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now - in XAML you attach it to your ViewModel like this:

```
<UserControl
     xmlns:VSManagerEx=clr-namespace:Namespace.namespace;assembly=Assembly01"
     VSManagerEx:VisualStateManagerEx.VisualState="{Binding Path=ViewModelVisualState, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     ...
     ...
```

Now your VSM in XAML is bound to `ViewModelVisualState` property in ViewModelBase (or whatever will be bound to `DataContext` of this `UserControl`. So Actually in your ViewModelBase you using is like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base class for all 'view-models'
/// </summary>
[Export(typeof(ViewModelBase))]
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INavigationAware, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SynchronizationContext parentSyncContent;

    #region VisualState
    private string viewModelVisualState = string.Empty;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the state of the view model visual.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The state of the view model visual.
    /// </value>
    public virtual string ViewModelVisualState
    {
        get { return viewModelVisualState; }
        set
        {
            viewModelVisualState = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(this, "ViewModelVisualState");
        }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Sender">The sender.</param>
    /// <param name="PropertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(object Sender, string PropertyName)
    {
        parentSyncContent.Post((state) =>
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(Sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }, null);
    }


    ...
    ...
```

So - in any ViewModel that inherit from this ViewModelBase could declare it own VMS states and manage them like this:

```
    [Export(typeof(IViewModel1))
    public ViewModel1 : ViewModelBase, IViewModel1
    {

          private const string VM_STATE_WORKING = "WorkingState";

          internal void StartWorking()
          {
               this.ViewModelVisualState = VM_STATE_WORKING;
    ...
    ...
```

Regards question 2: No - you don't need to declare any additional Views inside anything. Read PRISM documentation about Navigation. There's great examples on how to create View/ViewModel that support various presentation logic.

Is this helpful to you ?

Comment: Thanks Jasper, I have used the "DataStateBehavior" and it is working as excpected ... Of course you need blend for this to work.